# Can't open dialog activity from notification in API 19

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, dialog

***The problem is caused by other factors. Case closed. Thanks to @Mike M. for his help.***

I wrote an dialog activity and I tried to start the activity when clicking a notification. The notification is started by a service. **It starts in API 22, but it doesn't work in API 19.** In API 19, when clicking the notification, instead of showing the dialog notification, it brings another activity to the foreground. Below are relevant codes:

This is the dialog activity in the manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".DialogEventActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=".DialogEventActivity"
        android:theme="@style/DialogTransparent"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog_event" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is the style

```
<style name="DialogTransparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

This is the code in the service that starts the notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.todo_logo))
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notificatioin_new_task))
            .setOngoing(true);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogEventActivity.class);
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(alarmPendingIntent);
manager.notify(NEW_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results on a device running API 19.

Comment: @MikeM. what do you mean? You mean on your device it runs normally?

Comment: Yes, it runs normally.

Comment: on which model? @MikeM.

Comment: Very strange. The problem must be caused elsewhere. Thanks for testing it. Really appreciate it.